# Anaconda Environment - Copy from Linux to Windows

Tags: python, anaconda

If I want to share anaconda environments, I could export using `conda env export > py35.yml` and import it in another server using `conda env create -f py35.yml`.

It works well if they are in same flavor of Linux. How to copy the environment from Linux to Windows?

If there are no matching packages in Windows, it fails with
`Error: No packages found in current win-64 channels matching: packagename`

Is there a way to ignore packages that couldn't be installed and move on to installing others, instead of hard fail?

Comment: Hi @joel, does it help? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/conda-support-creating-conda-environment.html

Comment: @AndyK, I can create an env in Windows but want to copy all the packages I had custom installed from another environment in different OS.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `--from-history` flag when exporting. In the [documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#sharing-an-environment), it says this removes platform dependencies from the package list.

Full command would look like something like this:

```
conda env export --from-history -> py35.yml
```